# Intermittent DB connectivity error - RDS - MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have my servers within a  restricted VPC and have separate subnets for Instance and RDS. These subnets are routed to each other and communicate.

I have an application which connects to the DB, intermittently it throws the following error "A network-related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible" .

RDS MSSQL -  Mirrored between 2 AZ's

Can someone direct me to resolution please?

Tried adding host entries for name resolution
ensured connectivity between the instance and RDS is available

Comment: You could activate VPC Flow Logs to look at the network traffic headers. It would show whether traffic was rejected by the VPC. Then, when the application experiences this type of error, you could look at the logs to see if there were any corresponding messages. It could possibly be caused by network bandwidth limitations, especially if the EC2 instance is a small instance type (eg micro, small, medium).

Comment: Hello @JohnRotenstein Thank you for responding. We run on t2.large instances.. Probably I should move it to a different instance type and check the fucntionality..

Comment: The subnets "communicate" how? Sounds like the inbound security groups (RDS) or outbound security groups (app server/s) are not allowing traffic tcp/1433.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning An intermittent error would not be caused by a Security Group configuration. It's more likely related to something that regularly changes, like RAM, CPU or Network. If it were a permanent error, then you would be correct.